# Indirect object pronouns confusion

Tags: pronombres

> **Le** pegó un par de puñetazos que **le** hicieron sangre y **le** arrancó el aparato de las manos.  ([Source](https://elpais.com/politica/2019/10/30/actualidad/1572463596_443236.html))

This refers to a man and a woman fighting. How do I know who "le" refers to? Is it the woman or man?

Comment: Could you add some more context? Also if you have the source (a book?).

Comment: Statistically speaking, the probable gender arrangement is the perpetrator being male.  But the sentence gives no indication.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link.  Do you see that it's completely clear who's who from the context?  // Note, when a Spanish speaker makes a statement without enough context for the listener/reader to know who's who, then they will not do so much omitting of subjects.  For example: *El tipo le pegó un par de puñetazos a la frutera que le hicieron sangre y le arrancó el aparato que tenía en la mano.*

Comment: Mmm.. thanks. I still think it may be hard for non-native speakers to decipher this at times, but I take your point on the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no way to know who is being attacked, or perpetrating the aggression, with that phrase alone.**

The sentence uses a pronoun le which is valid for both masculine or feminine subjects.

> le [source)[1)
>
> (...) 2. pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. Forma que, en dativo, designa a la persona a la que se dirige quien habla o escribe.

*Update*: the news article that you included in the comment shows the context to know that it was a woman who got hit —cowardly so, from a man punishing her with a politically loaded reason.

Regarding the grammar question, on the possibilities of the language, to be explicit about the gender with that sole sentence  the femenine third person pronoun ***la*** [source](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NWnohQu) would suffice

The  sentence would have been unambiguous had it been written to read:

> *Le pegó un par de puñetazos, que la hicieron sangrar, y le arrancó el aparato de las manos.*  [ made her bleed ]

Comment: https://elpais.com/politica/2019/10/30/actualidad/1572463596_443236.html. La peligrosa decisión de vender peras de Lleida. I think it s a bit annoying that you need a context to understand the subject unlike in English, She hit him or He hit her. Why can this happen? This happens a lot.  .    I know in both languages it can happen if the 2 subjects are both  men  or women and a wider context is needed. I realise it was the woman ho got hit but is there a way of being clearer within a sentence alone? It can get confusing at times